# add MySQL schema from a different machine

Tags: mysql, copy-paste, error-code

One of our MySQL servers crashed. I copied all the physical data into my flash disk.

Now I need to copy it to my developer machine so i could somehow recover the records. A simple copy and paste to my MySQL data directory won't work as I always encounter this error: **Error Code: 1146. Table '*thisdb*.*thisTable*' doesn't exist** although the new schema is now visible in my workbench.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the table in an empty database and afterwards copy the raw data in to the dir's.

Usually that's what backups are for.

As a rule of thumb, one can say:

harddisks **will** fail.

Sooner or later.

I haven't ever seen a harddisk which did not fail ...

Comment: Hi Axel, Thanks for your help although I can't seem to get the results I wanted. I added a new test schema. After that I stopped the MySQL service from services.msc; and then pasted the thisTable.FRM to the directory under that schema; restarted the mysql service again; opened the workbench; The "transferred" tables are there but when I try to execute a select query from it, I would get the same "Error Code: 1146. Table 'thisdb.*thisTable*' doesn't exist". What do you think have I done wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: Usually there are three files `.MYI`, `.MYD` and `.frm`, did you copy all three?